# app show up only after reboot - adb push command

Tags: android, adb

When pushing an apk-file to my samsung galaxy s3 through the command

```
adb push myapp.apk data/app
```

the app does not automatically shows up - as it does when compiling and uploding it through Eclipse. I have to restart every time

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to install an app via adb you should use:

```
adb install myapp.apk
```

These are the option flags available:

```
adb install [-lrtsd] <file>
adb install-multiple [-lrtsdp] <file...>   
    - push this package file to the device and install it
      (-l: forward lock application)
      (-r: replace existing application)
      (-t: allow test packages)
      (-s: install application on sdcard)
      (-d: allow version code downgrade)
      (-p: partial application install)
```

Comment: Could you tell what does `-p` flag does? What would partial application install mean?